# How to validate a password IF user input is mobile, ELSE user input in email

Tags: php, validation, registration

Im a newb to PHP and coding in general.  Im following a tutorial.  It includes building a registration form with a 'mobile or email' input, something typical of Facebook or Amazon.  The code is an IF/ELSE statement. IF user inputs a phone number, validate everything, ELSE user inputs an email, validate everything.

While the password validation works with a mobile number, the password validation (literally the same code block) does not work with an email. Instead a user can register with an email with only 1 character in the password field.  However, the username is still validated, as is checking if the email is already in the database.  This is a problem within the tutorial's code itself too, not just my own.  I've tried reworking the code a number times over a few days but I'm just too inexperienced to know what to do.  I've searched through stackoverflow for similar problems but didnt find anything that was relevant to my specific issue.   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
require 'connect/DB.php';
require 'core/load.php';

/**

* If first-name is left blank, the submit button is not active. 
* If it isnt empty, variables will be created from the form input.

*/

if( isset($_POST['first-name']) && !empty($_POST['first-name']))
{
    $upFirst = $_POST['first-name'];
    $upLast = $_POST['last-name'];
    $upEmailMobile = $_POST['email-mobile'];
    $upPassword = $_POST['up-password'];
    $birthDay = $_POST['birth-day'];
    $birthMonth = $_POST['birth-month'];
    $birthYear = $_POST['birth-year'];    
    
    if(!empty($_POST['gen']))
    {
        $upgen = $_POST['gen'];
    }
    
//  create birth variable, made up of the three variables for year, month and day   
 
    $birth = ''.$birthYear.'-'.$birthMonth.'-'.$birthDay.'';

    
//  Validate that the form fields are not empty.  If they are, return error msg.
    
    if(empty($upFirst) or empty($upLast) or empty($upEmailMobile) or empty($upgen))
    {
        $error = 'All feilds are required';
    }
    
/** 

* Now that the form is filled, check the input of each field with the following variable
* Create screenname variable from first name and last name.

*/  
    else
    {
        $first_name = $loadFromUser->checkInput($upFirst);
        $last_name = $loadFromUser->checkInput($upLast);
        $email_mobile = $loadFromUser->checkInput($upEmailMobile);
        $password = $loadFromUser->checkInput($upPassword);
        $screenName = ''.$first_name.'_'.$last_name.'';
        
/**

* Check if the user's screenname is already in the database, if so, assign a random digit to their screenname
* Create userlink variable from screenname and random digit.

*/
        
        if(DB::query('SELECT screenName FROM users WHERE screenName = :screenName', array(':screenName' => $screenName )))
        {    
            $screenRand = rand();
            $userLink = ''.$screenName.''.$screenRand.'';
        }
        
        else
        {
            $userLink = $screenName;
        }

/** 

* Now we know a user has filled out the form, we've assigned them a screenName. Time to validate
* Check if a user entered an email that meets validation criteria

*/
        
        
        if(!preg_match("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$^",$email_mobile))
        {
    
/** 

* If the email format is not correct, check to see if a mobile format is correct.
* If neither is correct, send user an error message

*/
            if(!preg_match("^[0-9]{11}^", $email_mobile))
            {
                $error = 'Email id or Mobile number is not correct. Please try again.';
            }
 
/** 

* If the email or mobile format is correct, check to see which one they entered.  
* if its the correct format for a mobile number then validate password

*/
            else
            {
                
                $mob = strlen((string)$email_mobile);

                if($mob > 11 || $mob < 11)
                {
                    $error = 'Mobile number is not valid';
                }
                
                else if(strlen($password) <5 || strlen($password) >= 60)
                {
                    $error = 'Password is not correct';
                }
                
/** 

* If password passes validation, check to see if mobile number is already in use
* If it is, send error message to user

*/
                
                else
                {
                    if(DB::query('SELECT mobile FROM users WHERE mobile=:mobile', array(':mobile'=>$email_mobile)))
                    {
                        $error = 'Mobile number is already in use.';
                    }
 
/** 

* Now phone number and password pass validation, create a user including user ID.
* Create token, set cookie and redirect the user to index.php

*/
                    
                    else
                    {
                        $user_id=$loadFromUser->create('users', array('first_name'=>$first_name,'last_name'=>$last_name, 'mobile' => $email_mobile, 'password'=>password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT),'screenName'=>$screenName,'userLink'=>$userLink, 'birthday'=>$birth, 'gender'=>$upgen));

                        $loadFromUser->create('profile', array('userId'=>$user_id, 'birthday'=> $birth, 'firstName' => $first_name, 'lastName'=>$last_name, 'profilePic'=>'assets/image/defaultProfile.png','coverPic'=>'assets/image/defaultCover.png', 'gender'=>$upgen));

                        $tstrong = true;
                        $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $tstrong));
                        $loadFromUser->create('token', array('token'=>sha1($token), 'user_id'=>$user_id));

                        setcookie('FBID', $token, time()+60*60*24*7, '/', NULL, NULL, true);

                        header('Location: index.php');


                    }
                }
            }
        }
 
        
/** 

* Now after checking if the email or mobile format is correct, check to see which one they entered
* if its the correct format for an email and validate first name
*/
  
        else
        {
            if(!filter_var($email_mobile))
            {
                $error = "Invalid Email Format";
            }
            
            else if(strlen($first_name) > 20)         
            {
                $error = "Name must be between 2-20 character";
            }
/* 

* If the user entered the correct email and name format, validate password

*/
            else if(strlen($password) <5 || strlen($password) >= 60)
            {
                $error = "The password is either too short or too long";
            }

/** 

* If password passes validation, check to see if email is already in use
* If it is, send error message to user
*/
  
            
            else
            {
                if((filter_var($email_mobile,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) && $loadFromUser->checkEmail($email_mobile) === true)
                {
                    $error = "Email is already in use";
                }
   
/** 

* Now email and password pass validation, create a user including user ID.
* Create token, set cookie and redirect the user to index.php

*/
                else
                {
                    $user_id = $loadFromUser->create('users', array('first_name'=>$first_name,'last_name'=>$last_name, 'email' => $email_mobile, 'password'=>password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT),'screenName'=>$screenName,'userLink'=>$userLink, 'birthday'=>$birth, 'gender'=>$upgen));

                    $loadFromUser->create('profile', array('userId'=>$user_id, 'birthday'=>$birth, 'firstName' => $first_name, 'lastName'=>$last_name, 'profilePic'=>'assets/image/defaultProfile.png','coverPic'=>'assets/image/defaultCover.png', 'gender'=>$upgen));

                    $tstrong = true;
                    $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(64, $tstrong));
                    $loadFromUser->create('token', array('token'=>sha1($token), 'user_id'=>$user_id));

                    setcookie('FBID', $token, time()+60*60*24*7, '/', NULL, NULL, true);

                    header('Location: index.php');

                }
            }
        }
    }
}


?> ```
````

Comment: You should try to group some functionalities into functions and avoid using more than 1 level of conditions (condition inside of a condition). If you do that I am quite sure that you will find the solution in a few seconds ;)

Comment: It's a big chunk of code, and thank you for formatting it carefully, but squinting and scrolling, I don't think the email validation success goes through that block of code. I think it drops to the bottom. Also, your email regex will reject valid email addresses, and I know when I fill out a form and I'm rejected exactly which terrible piece of email validation advice the programmer used. That regex should die, and anyone still promoting it should be cast out.